# Change Datatype in Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and one column Quantity has the below values

```
Col1
20,000
20
-10,000
-50
```

I want to convert this column to a float, as later I am doing a comparison with a floating number to filter some rows. However I get some or the other error: "Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

I think I found the issue, when it reads the value "-50", it reads it as a float, so no "str" accessor is valid. While loading the csv file the column is an object type series

my code looks like

```
df['Qty'] = np.where(~df['Qty'].str.contains(','),df['Qty'],df['Qty'].str.replace(",",""))
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].astype(float)

How can I resolve this issue?
```

Comment: Use `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: if I do to_numeric I get the error "ValueError: Unable to parse string "20,000" at position 0". @yatu

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(series, errors='coerce')`

Comment: Can you share the code for loading the CSV? The dtype can be selected there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas Dataframe to Float with commas and negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192323/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-float-with-commas-and-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Col1'].astype(str).str.replace(',',''))
```